# Magmi deletes base image

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

I asked [a question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158311/magmi-deletes-base-image) in magento stack exchange about magmi image upload. I didn't get any response till now. I wanted to ask the SO community the same question to see if I can get any help. I'll copy the question here.

I am using Magmi to upload images to products in magento. Magmi version is 0.7.21. I am having some issues while uploading new images to products that already has some images.

The issue is that, when I upload new images with new base image set, the old base image gets deleted. The behaviour I expect is to change the base image flag and keep the old base image in gallery instead of completely removing the old image.

I am completely new to Magmi. I am not sure what details are needed to figure out this issue. I can update the question if someone ask me for more specific details. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? I know this is not the right place to ask the question and I did try asking the question in magento stackexchange as explained in the question. I asked the same question here because I was certain that I'll get some help here.

Answer (score 0):

In magmi uploading the base image will overwrite current base image - this is just default magmi behaviour. you need to either include the new base image under the base image header and add the existing images as media gallery images under a media_gallery header in the following format - sku_01.jpg::sku_label;/sku_02.jpg::sku_label;/sku_03.jpg::sku_label; or forget about the base image and add the new image under the media_gallery header.

Comment: When you said 'add the existing images as media gallery', does that mean I have to upload the existing images again to media/import directory? Or just putting the value in csv is enough?

Comment: putting the value in the csv should be enough

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But it didn't work. The old base image still gets deleted from media gallery.